# Symfony No Route To Host on edit, but works fine on findAll

Tags: mysql, symfony

I am using Symfony 3.0.4. I have the error

```
[2016-05-20 08:50:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host" at /var/www/WebProduction/products.markettraders.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host at /var/www/WebProduction/products.markettraders.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:103, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host at /var/www/WebProduction/products.markettraders.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host at /var/www/WebProduction/products.markettraders.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"} []
[2016-05-20 08:50:26] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
```

This is strange because the indexAction is working perfectly, only the Edit Action is NOTWorking, on all of my edit routes. There have been no changes in the code to cause this to happen.

What have I inadvertantly changed in my MySQL configuration that allows Doctrine to find everything on the indexAction but then error out on the editAction?

**EDIT**
Forgive me.... The code is below. It works in my local environment. It does not work in prod. The error above comes from the prod.log.

In addition the indexAction controller works as well.

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing AOD Technical Analysis page entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="aod_technical_analysis_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, AodTechnicalAnalysis $aod_tech)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($aod_tech);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\AodTechnicalAnalysisType', $aod_tech);
    $editForm->remove('currencypair');
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($aod_tech);
        $em->flush();

        $session = $request->getSession();
        $message = 'The change was succesfully saved for ' . $aod_tech->getCurrencypair();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', $message);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('aod_technical_analysis_index');
    }

    return $this->render('aod_tech/edit.html.twig', array(
        'aod_tech' => $aod_tech,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of the error and the code that is related to it. Otherwise we can only guess what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't think the code was relevant as it worked before with no changes in the code. It also works in my dev environment.

Comment: Are you sure that the database credentials are correct? It looks like the application is not able to reach the database host.

Comment: I am sure. Like I said the indexAction controller uses the same credentials

Comment: Have you tried appending "app_dev.php" on your URL to get the debug web toolbar? I have found this to be more helpful compared to logs. You might need to edit the "web/app_dev.php" to add your browser's IP address.

Comment: And does your `indexAction()` controller actually involve database access?

Comment: @AlvinBunk thanks for your suggestion. Turns out this application has connections to several different databases across 3 different IP addresses.  I have proper security group configurations (Amazon Web Services) for the part of the application I'm working on, but not for 2 of the other databases. That being said your suggestion helped me hunt it down. Please answer the question so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried appending "app_dev.php" on your URL to get the debug web toolbar? I have found this to be more helpful compared to logs. You might need to edit the "web/app_dev.php" to add your browser's IP address.

Comment: The actual answer was found in the trace logs provided by this suggestion.  In order to clear cache in any environment Symfony must have a clear connection to all database's/servers listed in its configuration. In my case 2 of the databases I connect to were restricted by security groups on the AWS end.